# In .net core, do some logging right after user logs in. And NOT on every request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-core, windows-authentication

I'm working on a .net Core 5.0 MVC project that the user logs in using Windows Authentication.
So there is no Login controller. The browser itself asks for username and password and redirects the user to my controllers.

And I want to do some logging right after the user logs in. I want to log to the database some information regarding the User + Date + IP.

If I understood correctly, if I use .net core middleware (if I create my own middleware and place on Startup.cs), I will be logging on every request. And that's not what I want. I want just the first login of each user.

Is there a way to do that? I've tried to search SO and MS docs, but couldn't find an answer.

Is there any interceptor that happens only after Windows Auth login?

Thanks!

Comment: *if I use .net core middleware, I will be logging on every request.* -> what middleware and what logging system are we talking about?

Comment: @PeterBons I want to log to a table in the Database. When I say middleware, I'm talking about creating my own and placing on Startup.cs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this is by hanging off something you store somewhere. There isn't anything out of the box that I can think of.

A cookie would work but is too volatile. The only safe and consistent way I can think of is to hang off a value stored somewhere in your user store (database) that is a booleon flag that once you have done your first login stuff, you set to true and can check on subsequent requests.

Much like you are probably doing with email confirmation if you are using the standard ASP.NET Identity and demanding verified email addresses.